# Deploying Rails Application in a restricted server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, bundle

I am trying to deploying my rails application to a restricted server. And I am not able to install ruby and gems from the open internet because the server is restricted in the network. That server is new it dont have any needful library, database and apache to deploying the app. Please provide me the best way to get all the library and needful gems to keep the app running.

Comment: Can you run a virtual machine on the server?  If so then potentially you could run everything inside the VM.  You would need an http server on the main server which proxies the request into the VM.